# How to modify an element in Array list

Tags: java, arraylist

I have created the below arrayLIST .  I want to modify the phone number of djohn@gmail.com. Can you please let me know how to modify it. Thanks in advance

```
 private static List<Customer> customers;
{
    customers = new ArrayList();
    customers.add(new Customer(101, "John", "Doe", "djohn@gmail.com", "121-232-3435"));
    customers.add(new Customer(201, "Russ", "Smith", "sruss@gmail.com", "343-545-2345"));
    customers.add(new Customer(301, "Kate", "Williams", "kwilliams@gmail.com", "876-237-2987"));

}
```

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PatchMapping.html ?

Comment: you have to have a customer dao method for update, then get customer based on id, and then update the fields passed by patch.

Comment: `customers.get(0).setPhoneNumber("xxx-xxx-xxxx");` assuming `Customer` class has getters and setters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have getters and setters, loop through the list and update the phone number when the e-mail matches the one you want

```
for (Customer customer : customers){
    if (customer.getEmail().equals("djohn@gmail.com")){
        customer.setPhoneNumber("xxx-xxx-xxxx");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With Java 8 streams, use a predicate to find the customer, and `Optional.ifPresent()` to update the value.

```
customers.stream()
         .filter(customer -> "djohn@gmail.com".equals(customer.getEmail()))
         .findFirst()
         .ifPresent(customer -> customer.setPhoneNumber(2222222));
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar with the solution provided by @Sean Patrick Floyd, if you want want to modify all the customers with email "djohn@gmail.com":

```
customers.stream().filter(e -> "djohn@gmail.com".equals(e.getEmail()))
                  .forEach(e -> e.setPhoneNumber("xxx-xxx-xxxx"));
```